# While setting up synchronization for bitbucket repo getting error as not a git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

While trying to setup a synchronization for a bitbucket repo on my local server, I am getting the error **not a git repo**. Below is the command which I fired:

```
$ git --git-dir=~/gitRepo/my_repo.git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:username/my_repo.git
fatal: Not a git repository: '~/gitRepo/my_repo.git'
```

Even I tried to init the repo (as previously I was not doing that) but still same error I got. Below are the steps which I followed after looking tutorials on Git (as I am new to Git so sorry if I ask very basic question)

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/gitRepo/my_repo/.git/
$ git --git-dir=~/gitRepo/my_repo remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:username/my_repo.git
fatal: Not a git repository: '~/gitRepo/my_repo'
```

Is something I am missing. Basically I am trying to setup a sync of Redmine with BitBucket and this is one of the steps required.

Comment: Try omitting the `--git-dir` argument, just running the command from the `my_repo` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't initialize the repo when doing your first command, then the error message is normal: you need to create a repo before adding it any remote.

As for your second error message: If you are in the git repo directory itself (which you are after a `git init`), then, as [Issac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371116/isaac) comments, you don't need a `--git-dir` parameter.
But if you still want to add an `--git-dir` argument, then the path referenced by a `--git-dir` for a non-bare repo must ends in `/.git` (like you did in your first command).

Even after creating a git repo in `~/gitRepo/my_repo`:

- `~/gitRepo/my_repo` is not a git repo
- `~/gitRepo/my_repo/.git` is